# Integrate Orage Globaltime with Clock

Tags: xfce, calendar

I want to integrate Orage Globaltime into the clock in my xubuntu 14.04. Currently, I have both applications separately. For example, if I click the clock in the panel a calendar appears. However, you cannot register events there (it's just a clock app). If I click the Orage indicator the Orage calendar pops up, where I can see/create events. What I'm looking for is to combine both apps so in the panel it shows the time (which is not possible with Orage) but when I click it a calendar appears where I can annotate events. I want this just to reduce the number of icons in my panel.

If this is not possible, is there an alternative app for this? I have seen several calendars but none have the role of clock too. I imagine that if there is no such program then I would have to make a feature request to the xfce4-dev team.

Comment: It's a good question. My workaround was to delete the clock. Add the Orage cal app to the taskbar, then move the Orage cal popup to the lower right corner just above the time app. It holds that position after that.

Comment: Good trick! You end up without the clock though. I could always keep the clock but it's always nice to have a more clean panel.

Comment: You can turn the Orage app into a new clock. I didn't want to put a lot time in exact steps without knowing if it met your needs, but I can turn it into an answer that addresses the clock issue.

Comment: That would be great. I'm planning to make a feature request to the xfce4 team anyway. This should be much more simple.

Comment: Oh, solution is trivial. Now I get it. Yes, delete clock, add Orage clock, deselect systray icon from Orage Preferences and voala, you have the clock and the calendar integrated! Please write the answer and I will accept it as final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do exactly what you want, but I use the following workaround for the problem.

1. Delete the standard clock from the taskbar.
2. Add the Orage clock to the taskbar in its place.
3. Click the Orage clock. By default it opens the single month calendar window in the center of the screen. But if you drag it down to the lower, right corner just above the Orage clock, it will hold that position the next time you open it.
4. Optional: Delete the the Orage system tray icon using Orage preferences for a clean setup that mimics the traditional arrangement.

Comment: The only problem with this is that now you lose the right click menu, where you can easily add new events and change preferences. I see no workaround for this.

Comment: Yeah, that's frustrating, but that's why I kept the Orage app in the systray along with changing the setup.